# Trouble with oauth2client.client.Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gdata-api

I'm trying to use OAuth2 with my App Engine application, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: IOError ([Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'credentials.dat')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1332, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 412, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~art-everywhere/7.385356767964097452/main.py", line 438, in upload_putphoto
    gd_client = PicasaWA.login()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~art-everywhere/7.385356767964097452/main.py", line 1653, in login
    storage.put(credentials)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~art-everywhere/7.385356767964097452/oauth2client/client.py", line 325, in put
    self.locked_put(credentials)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~art-everywhere/7.385356767964097452/oauth2client/file.py", line 113, in locked_put
    f = open(self._filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'credentials.dat'
```

It looks like there's a problem with the write used in the library.

Here's a snippet of the code I used:

```
def login(cls):
    scope = 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/'
    user_agent = 'picasawebuploader'
    # credential_store = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], "credentials.dat")

    storage = Storage("credentials.dat")
    # storage = Storage(credential_store)
    credentials = storage.get()

    # user = users.get_current_user()
    # storage = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user.user_id(), 'credentials')
    # credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        flow = flow_from_clientsecrets("client_secrets.json", scope=scope, redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
        uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        logging.info("uri: %s", uri)
        webbrowser.open(uri)
        code = "Here I posted the code retrived by the autentication"
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
        storage.put(credentials)

    if (credentials.token_expiry - datetime.utcnow()) < timedelta(minutes=5):
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        credentials.refresh(http)

    gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(source=user_agent,
                                                   email=USERNAME,
                                                   additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % credentials.access_token})

    return gd_client
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't create files in AppEngine like you would on a regular filesystem, [it's read-only](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/). You need to use special [AppEngine credentials and storage objects](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#credentials).

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this App engine limitation. But, as you can see in the  code snippet, I used the special storage object given by App Engine Oauth2 library. Looking at the tutorials it seems to me that I followed the right steps... Could you tell what am I doing wrong and how to correct the code to make it work? I would be very thankful to you if you could help me solve this annoying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue running the devserver on my local machine. The solution was not pretty, but [this change](http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/enable-filesystem-writes-in-gae-dev-appserver/) solved it for me. I'm not sure if you'd be able run `storage.put(credentials)` from within appengine. This might be where a lot of the issue came from. Doing the oauth flow as part of a separate script, and then loading the credentials from the file actually worked for me after modifying the devserver.

I highly doubt that this would actually work in production though, so you might want to look into [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: I also got the credentials running a separate script, but the access token could expire and it is not good for production as you said. Thank you for the link! I finally got it working. The Sheet Api example should be updated, because the oauth flow is repeated several times and it tries to write the credentials in a file (which is not supported by AppEngine).